# getConnectors in SVN Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins, git-svn

I am attempting to retrieve code from an SVN repository into Eclipse. I am in the process of installing SVN plugins by navigating to Help > Install New Software and providing the following site location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.0/update-site/

However, when I go to Window > Preferences > SVN > Get Connectors, I encounter the issue depicted in this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Can someone please assist me in resolving this issue and successfully installing the SVN connectors in Eclipse?

I have tried the above mentioned procedure in eclipse oxygen with the following version Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a).

Am I missing anything ?